# ¿Cómo hacer que un SD ocupe toda la pantalla aunque la navegación sea Split sobre iPad?

Tags: genexus

Tengo una app que trabaja sobre iPad con navegación Split y necesito que la primera vez que comienza muestre otra panel pero en pantalla completa.

He intentado con distintas programaciones pero la pantalla se me muestra en el list o en su defecto en el contenedor.

GeneXus Evo3 U5.

Comment: bienvenido a es.stackoverflow quizas le interese mirar este link http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

En el evento `Split.Start` del `Main`, haces el llamado a ese `SDPanel` que quieres mostrar por primera vez.

A su vez en el theme que la aplicación esté usando, debes agregar una nueva clase de tipo `Form` a la que le configuras:

```
Call Type = Popup
Target Size = Large
```

Por último, le asignas ésta nueva clase al `Form` del `SDPanel` que vas a ver en full screen.

Saludos.